# PopUp view in another view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, popup

I've searched on the web with no succsess. I actually just found some popups with html or just text. I would like to make a view that pops up. In the view, should be some content, a button and maybe an imageview. I've found some apps, which are using this popup views so far. The popup displaying is animated. Here I've some pictures:

1.
[image]

and then it grown up till it fits:

[image]

does anybody know how to do this? It would be awesome if someone has a code snipped for me to present this view in portrait mode.

Thanks.

Comment: you can do it by presenting a modalView with presentation style `UIModalPresentationFormSheet`

Comment: But isnt that just for Ipad?

Comment: ya it works only in iPad also you can't use popover in iPhone. So you need some ustom control to do it in iPhone

Comment: +1 for nice question, also nice images :) (I like this game very much )

Comment: yes, I like it very much. completed two levels today :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[CocoaControls](http://www.cocoacontrols.com) has some things like this. Take a look at these:

- [KGModal for iOS](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/kgmodal)
- [MJPopupViewController for iOS](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/mjpopupviewcontroller)
- [UAModalPanel for iOS](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/uamodalpanel)
- [RNBlurModalView for iOS](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/rnblurmodalview)

Comment: @MidhunMP Thanks! I didn't get the +1 though!

Comment: @NoahRaissi I can't really offer any other solutions. These controls do most of the work for you, so if you have an error, it's probably worth tracking down. You can always modify one of them to suit you.

Comment: one more time: +1 for the nice links :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by presenting a modalView with **Presentation Style** `UIModalPresentationFormSheet`.

It'll look like:

[image: UIModalPresentationFormSheet]

You need to change the height and width according to your need also you can customize the appearance.
Please refer.

1. [UIModalPresentationStyle](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UIModalPresentationStyle)
2. [ModalViewControllers](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ModalViewControllers/ModalViewControllers.html)

If you need it in iPhone use [FPPopover](http://www.50pixels.com/blog/labs/open-library-fppopover-ipad-like-popovers-for-iphone/) or [Modal View in Iphone](http://doganberktas.com/2010/05/18/adding-transparent-modal-view-programatically-iphone/)

Comment: But isnt that just for Ipad?

Comment: @NoahRaissi: ya it works only in iPad also you can't use popover in iPhone. So you need some ustom control to do it in iPhone

Comment: well thanks but I will try the safe method of KGModal which is in the other awnser thanks! :D

Comment: ok, also check http://www.50pixels.com/blog/labs/open-library-fppopover-ipad-like-popovers-for-iphone/

Comment: custom modal view in iphone : http://doganberktas.com/2010/05/18/adding-transparent-modal-view-programatically-iphone/